# Callout VBA word

Tags: excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office

Estoy haciendo una macro en Visual Basic para word. Tengo ya este código:

```
Set Callout = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCallout( _
Type:=msoCalloutThree, _
Left:=170, Top:=119.5, Width:=widthsize1, Height:=heightsize1)

Callout.Callout.Accent = msoFalse
Callout.Callout.Border = msoTrue

Callout.Callout.Angle = msoCalloutAngle30
Callout.TextFrame.TextRange = StepText1
```

Y mi callout sale de la siguiente forma:
[image: ejemplo 1]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la dirección de la flecha si yo necesito que salga hacía arriba con la macro?

De esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!